# How to move cursor back one character stuck at SOL instead of jump to previous EOL?

Tags: cursor, back, eol

I gvim, when I usu the cursor movement key to go back one character, it does not wrap around to the previous line, but is stuck at the start of the current line.
Is there any flag to control this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. See `:help 'whichwrap'` for details:

```
'whichwrap' 'ww'    string  (Vim default: "b,s", Vi default: "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Allow specified keys that move the cursor left/right to move to the
    previous/next line when the cursor is on the first/last character in
    the line.  Concatenate characters to allow this for these keys:
        char   key    mode  ~
         b    <BS>   Normal and Visual
         s    <Space>    Normal and Visual
         h    "h"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         l    "l"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         <    <Left>     Normal and Visual
         >    <Right>    Normal and Visual
         ~    "~"    Normal
         [    <Left>     Insert and Replace
         ]    <Right>    Insert and Replace
    For example: >
        :set ww=<,>,[,]
```